# Как бесплатно попробовать azure?

Tags: azure

Хочу начать работать с Azure, слышал что есть бесплатные способы это сделать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дополню ответ Mikhail Vaysman:

При регистрации нового аккаунта дается **12500 рублей (эквивалент 200$, если Вы из России) на 30 дней**.

**Внимание:** для регистрации необходимо указывать номер телефона и номер банковской карты с не 0 балансом, т.к. Microsoft делает тестовое списание небольшой суммы (не более 30 рублей) и ее возврат через некоторое время.

---

Если данного времени не достаточно для тестирования всех возможностей сервиса, можно воспользоваться программой поддержки разработчиков от Microsoft [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/dev-essentials/) которая дополнительно предоставит **1600 рублей (25$) ежемесячно в течение года**.

---

Если у вас уже есть идея проекта, который хочется реализовать на платформе azure - можно попробовать воспользоваться программой спонсорской поддержки стартапов от Microsoft [Bizspark](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ms-start), по данной программе каждому участнику стартапа будет предоставлено **9600 рублей (150$) в месяц** для использования облачных сервисов в своей разработке, программа рассчитана максимум на 5 участников, длительность - 1 год.

Answer (score 1):

Переходите по ссылке [Create your free Azure account today](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) и получаете кредит в 200$. Там же написано и про бесплатные сервисы.

Comment: И хотя ссылка по-прежнему работает в 2020 году -- регистрация из Russia по-прежнему закрыта.

Answer (score 1):

Если просто "попробовать" разнообразные сервисы в Ажуре, то на сайте обучения от МС по многим сервисам в процессе обучения предоставляется песочница.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/learn/browse/?products=azure

Как пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]