# Размещение сервера (бюджетный вариант)

Tags: веб-сервер

Нужно разместить сервер, на котором будет API, искала исключительно бесплатные варианты(это возможно?) Нужна не пробная версия, чтобы на несколько пробных дней, а на постоянное пользование. Если это возможно, то хотелось бы узнать как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Самый дешманский вариант на firstvds - 90 руб в месяц(OpenVZ).

Comment: Не знаю, позволяют ли они сейчас так же, но в свое время перенес один сайт на бесплатный OpenShift, до сих пор работает. Там недостатки - своя очень особенная среда, но, в принципе, можно вручную с бубном собрать почти что угодно, потом DNS - CNAME на сервера Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бесплатно и на вечность точно нет, но вот на год вполне можно выбрать из этих вариантов:

1. [Amazon EC2 + дополнительные сервисы](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/free/)
2. [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial)
3. [Про Microsoft Azure у меня уже есть отдельный ответ на SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707473/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-azure)

На всех 3 перечисленных платформах вы можете разместить свой код в контейнере облачного сервиса или развернуть собственную VM и проинсталлировать уже все на нее

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего бесплатных нету, но вы можете поискать бесплатный виртуальный хостинг с поддержкой php и на нем уже развернуть свое api