# Как удаленно подключиться к SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, клиент-сервер

Мне нужно сделать подключение с любого пк к удаленной бд на SQL Server (установлен на моем пк), свой сервер настроил на удаленный доступ по этому видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2T7PdDTAq8Y, на пк клиента установлненна индентичная версия SQL Server Express 2014 (у него тоже настроены удаленные подключения)
В программе строка подключения имеет вид: "Data Source=tcp:192.168.0.107, 1433;Initial Catalog=DanceStudioDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=admin"
порт 1433 открыт
пареметр Data Source пробывал менять на:
192.168.0.107

tcp:192.168.0.107

192.168.0.107, 1433

192.168.0.107\SQLEXPRESS

192.168.0.107\SQLEXPRESS, 1433

tcp:192.168.0.107\SQLEXPRESS

tcp:192.168.0.107\SQLEXPRESS, 1433

Вобщем я уже не знаю что еще можно писать, перечитал все что мог, и так как майкрософт писали делал https:// technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms345306(v=sql.100).aspx (удалите пробел после //) но всеравно ничего.
А вот что в ошибке пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам стоит добавить детали проблемы в вопрос, иначе вам будут отвечать наугад. сервер и клиент в тоже же сети? Какие сетевые адреса клиента и сервера? Или между ними есть NAT/интернет? ping между ними проходит?

Comment: в конечном продукте база данных будет стоять на платном хостинге, подключение к нему будет уже не таким муторным надеюсь?

Comment: на платном хостинге вам выдадут готовую строку подключения (если хостинг нормальный). другое дело, что сейчас непонятно, куда и как вы хотите подключиться. может быть на соседнюю машину, а вам уже насоветовали порты в nat пробрасывать и белый адрес покупать. хотя (может быть)  вам нужно просто на сервере удаленные подключения разрешить.

Comment: ну мой сервер в одной сети, а клиент на другой. Я так понял в процесе розработки работать на локальном сервере, а врелизе просто изменить строку подключения к хостингу

Comment: да, примерно так

Comment: @MaximKoylo предлагаю рассмотреть вариант начала работы с БД в облаке Azure, это может сэкономить времени  и не будет необходимости настройки локального SQl Server, разработчикам бесплатно дается подписка на год. Подробнее тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707473/Как-бесплатно-попробовать-azure

Answer (score 1):

192.168.0.107 - [это частный IP-адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81)
Доступ к таким адресам возможен только, если вы находитесь в той же подсети.

1. Предлагаю начать с отправки Ping на сервер.
2. Далее проверить, что порт (1433) открыт в firewall операционной системы, проверить доступность порта на сервере можно набрав в консоли windows (cmd): telnet 192.168.0.107 1433

Comment: Если мой IP частный то я же могу его сделать общедоступным верно? фаервол вообще отключен и на сервере и на клиенте

Comment: нет, не можете, проверьте адрес, который выдает 2ip.ru - это будет адрес, который виден как ваш через интернет

Comment: @MaximKoylo нужно делать альбомом портов в NAT. Порты на клиенте открывать не надо.

Comment: @MaximKoylo в вашем случае надо начать с получения белого ip-адреса, потом обеспечить проброс портов на вашем роутере в локальную сеть на ПК с SQL Server, а потом уже проводить тестирование